# Neo4j: Searching in graph for exact same sub-graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, apoc

I have currently the problem, that I want to find an exactly same subgraph under one other node.

To make it more specific. I have multiple repair guides which have multiple repair steps. The repair steps can exist also inside another repair guide. Now I want to find similar repair guides which have the exact same repair steps.

```
MATCH (mp1:Maintenance{name:'13 Years (325000 km)'})-[:HAS]->(ws:WorkStep)
WHERE id(mp1)=49214
with collect(ws) as workingssteps, mp1
MATCH (mp2:Maintenance)
```

Now I'm stuck, how to proceed further to iterate over mp2 to find the same working steps from mp1.

Thanks for any help or tips.
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of finding other `Maintenance` nodes connected to the same set of `WorkStep` nodes as a given `Maintenance` node:

```
MATCH (m:Maintenance)-[:HAS]->(w:WorkStep)
WHERE m.name = '13 Years (325000 km)'
WITH m, COLLECT(w) AS ws
MATCH (other:Maintenance)-[:HAS]->(w1:WorkStep)
WHERE w1 IN ws
WITH ws, other, COLLECT(w1) AS w1s
WHERE ALL(x IN ws WHERE x IN w1s)
RETURN other
```

I assume above that the `name` property of `Maintenance` nodes is unique. It is not generally a reliable practice to find a node/relationship by its the native ID, as the native ID can be reused after entity deletion. Also, the [ID()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id) function is now deprecated.